# Log file pattern matching

Tags: bash, unix, logging

i want to monitor application log file for specific error patterns on content added in since last 10 min (or since script last run) please not i dont want to monitor entire log file but only lines that are added in last 10 min, when patern is matched i want it displayed on screen. I'm confused how to achieve this thru script.

TIA
regards
tnt5273

Comment: Going to need an example of the log file in question (or at least some lines from it - different applications log in very different ways).

Comment: Could [`tail`](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-head-tail.html) be of any help?

Comment: hi oliver log contains different error codes and different exception errors its plain text format

Comment: The exact format of the lines in the logfile is needed. a vague description is not sufficient. Please update your question with an example of a few lines of your logfile.

Comment: Your question isn't about coding, as written it isn't appropriate for this site. ServerFault is probably a more suitable place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE=logfile
lines=$(wc -l < "$FILE")
while sleep 600; do
    clines=$(wc -l < "$FILE")
    diff=$(($clines - $lines))
    tail -$diff $FILE | grep PATTERN
    lines=$clines
done
```

Comment: thx perreal, this is closer to my requirement, i need a script which will run and exit after checking pattern in newly added lines, i think sleep will keep process running...

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to be describing is commonly achieved at a console by:

```
tail -F /path/to/my/file | grep "pattern"
```

This an idiom used by many system adminstrators.

---

There's another approach where you want to be alerted if a particular event is logged, but you don't want to watch for it.

The [Simple Event Correllator](http://simple-evcorr.sourceforge.net/) is a perl script designed to watch logs, correlate events and perform actions.

Comment: hi matt thx but tail -F can not be used as I'll be invoking script every 10 min thru monitoring tool (cannot run tail all the time)

Comment: Moreover tail -f will fail when the logs are rolled. it will keep pointing to the backed up log file.